# How to parse text for certain strings with PHP and regex

Tags: php, parsing

I am trying to parse some text and retrieve info inbetween two strings. The regex seems to be fine, but I still do not get any result.

The text string looks like this: ""`<h1 class="csc-firstHeader">Text I want to retrieve</h1></header>`

The php code I am using:

```
$start = preg_quote('Header">', '/'); 
$end = preg_quote('</h1>', '/');

$regex = '#'.$start.'(.*?)'.$end.'#';
echo $regex;

$code = preg_match($regex, $text, $matches);

print_r($code);
print_r($matches);
```

The result is unfortunately empty.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to escape `/` if you're using `#` for your regex delimiters.  The second parameter for `preg_quote` is your regex delimiter, which means your code should have been:

```
$start = preg_quote('some_text', '#'); 
$end = preg_quote('some_other_text', '#');
```

Comment: This unfortunately does not work either. The regex itself works if I test it with online tools but it does not work with php